# Tmux rebinding split-window does not work

Tags: tmux

I have the following minimal tmux config:

```
unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix C-a
bind C-a send-prefix

set -g history-limit 5000

setw -g mouse on
setw -g monitor-activity on

bind -n C-Left split-window -h
```

But pressing Ctrl+Left does not do anything. I also tried `bind -n C-Left split-window -h` but Ctrl+b Ctrl+Left did also nothing.

Isn't is possible to remap Ctrl?

Comment: Just to clarify: you want Ctrl+Left to perform the split-window operation without having to press the prefix key first? I.e. you want to press only Ctrl+Left instead of Ctrl+b Ctrl+Left (or in your case Ctrl+a Ctrl+Left) ?
Also, please add information about your OS and the window manager / Desktop environment you're using (if you're using Linux). This might be relevant, since Ctrl+Left might be a system shortcut.

Comment: Yes exactly. As splitting windows is a common operation or me, I would like to be able to perform this without hitting ctrl+a first. I'm running Fedora with the GNOME desktop and wayland display server. Also I'm using Kitty as a terminal if this is also helpful.

Comment: Sorry, don't know about Fedora. You might want to check your Gnome keyboard settings for Ctrl+Left bindings (see https://askubuntu.com/a/1421270/1134596 - that's Ubuntu specific, but might be relevant). 
If that doesn't help:  https://superuser.com/q/238545/611512 mentions some restrictions regarding Ctrl-Key combinations, so you might be out of luck / have to switch to a different key.